# Check the visibility or display of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 divs.By default, the visibility of all of them is set to "hidden". When I click a button,they get visible:

```
<script>

function fun(x)
{
    document.getElementById(x).style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden">div1</div><input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun('div1')">
<div id="div2" style="visibility:hidden">div2</div><input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun('div2')">
```

.
.
.
Is there any way to detect in the fun() function whether a div is visible or hidden so that by examining the state of the div(visible/hidden) it can be made hidden/visible just by clicking the button each time?

My second question is that(first one is already solved): suppose div1 is visible,now I click button number 2,as a result div2 will be also visible,but div1 appears hidden without clicking button number 1 again and so on...How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of property `visibility` and compare it with its possible values.

```
function fun(x)
{
    if( document.getElementById(x).style.visibility == "visible")
         document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    else
         document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

If you can use jQuery then you can use `show()`, `hide()` functions but they use `display` property instead of `visibility`.

Comment: There was a type copy if statement and try again, let me know if it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
function fun(x)
{
    document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = 
    (document.getElementById(x).style.visibility != "visible") ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is an option for you, you can use [jQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Toggle however toggles display (not visibility); if this is ok for you try:

```
function fun(x) {
    $("#"+x).toggle();
}
```

jQuery solution for toggling the visibility:

```
function fun(x) {
    var $obj = $("#"+x);
    $obj.css('visibility', $obj.css('visibility')=='hidden'?'visible':'hidden');
}
```

Comment: i cannot think about a simpler solution

Comment: Thanks  @R. Oosterholt

Comment: @A.Wolff but visibility and display does two different things

Answer (score 0):

In jquery :

```
if($('#div1').is('visible')) {
//  do something
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the element is taking no space (like `display:none`). It will not work with `visibility`

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use $(x).is(":visible")

```
function fun(x)
{
   if( $(x).is(":visible") ) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function toggle(x) {
    var style = document.getElementById(x).style;
    style.visibility = style.visibility == "visible" ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
}
```

or jQuery equivalent

```
function toggle(x) {
    $('#' + x).css(visible, function (_, visibility) {
        return visibility == "visible" ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
    })
}
```